# Unable to view the Query editor Grafana dashboard

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I am trying to create a dashboard in Grafana. In the UI, when I tried to create a new dashboard and add a panel, the query editor in the panel is not getting displayed.
[image]

It was initially working fine. Now facing this issue for newly created panels and also for existing panels.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the Query editor not to load may be due to browser cache. When I tried in Incognito, it works as before.